# How to index LLVM's libc++ in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: llvm, eclipse-cdt, libc++

On Ubuntu 14.04, I have llvm/clang and all the libraries installed. I am able to run the LLVM [Kaleidoscope example](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl3.html) from the command line with `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`

I tried importing the Kaleidoscope code into Eclipse CDT. I added the `/usr/include/c++/v1` path to the libc++ library. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Type 'std::string' could not be resolved
```

How do I fix it? Am I missing some defines?

Note: I'm not trying to compile the code through CDT. I'm just trying to get the indexing to work.

[image]

Comment: have you tried cmake cdt backend? May be helpful.